# Scala method: function with two groups of parameters

Tags: scala

I'm reading a scala source code. I see this method:

```
 def send[I <: IncomingMessage, O <: OutgoingMessage](
    botId: BotId,
    outgoingMessage: O,
    timeout: Int
  )(implicit
    mapping: MessageMapping[I, O],
    typeable: Typeable[I]
  ): Task[I] = {
    // some code
  }
```

I understand in scala, for define a method: `def methodName(params): returnType { ...}`. But on above code, the structure is: `def methodName(params)(params): return Type = { ... }`. I don't understand the second `(params)`. What are the differences between those 2 cases.

Comment: Functions can have multiple argument lists in Scala. What the intent of the second one is though may be answered in the docs for the function. The second argument list can be used to represent the body of a custom control structure.

Comment: When you have `def f(a: X)(b: Y): Z` you just call `f(a)` and the result is a function that would take a `b: Y`. It's called partial application.

Comment: @mfirry result of `f(a)` is not a function, still have to use `f(a) _`